# do the javascript array functions like reduce, filter, map generates memory allocations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, performance, memory

Maybe the answer is quite obvious, but I didn't find any answer related to this topic.

Do we allocate memory in the heap when we use array functions that return new instances of arrays?

I will try to clarify my question using a random example.
I have a list of numbers, and I want to filter the list to have the biggest 10 elements.

If I have to execute this function constantly, I am generating a lot of array instances, so it can lead to a potential memory problem. It can be fixed by just creating the 10 element array, then just reading the list and replacing the values with a simple for but... is it really necessary?

Comment: What do you need this for? Are you doing operations on very large arrays?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `typescript` and `performance`?

Comment: _"is it really necessary?"_ - No. Trust the environment you're executing the script in to do a good enough job to not cause memory leaks with (built-in) functions.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @OleMorud I am doing a videogame. Every game loop (every frame) will execute this function, so if i want to have a framerate of 60 frames per second, I will generate a new array instance every 16ms

Comment: @Andreas Because I think that memory can cause performance issues if it is not handled correctly, and because it is very related, I thought that people interested in performance would be interested in this topic.

Comment: I know about micro-optimisation, but I am just asking to see if anyone has faced situations where these kinds of things matter, so I will reformulate the question. Is creating a thousand arrays with those functions every ms worse than keeping one thousand arrays stored and recycling the instances? or really doesn't matter? @Andreas

Comment: That's a question for a profiler with a well-defined setup.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it is. This is the reason why I am here asking this question. To avoid doing all the work, and see if someone can share their experience and results.

Answer (score 0):

If the scope of your intermediate variables are managed correctly, the garbage collecting will clear up anything unnecessary. This article may help: https://blog.logrocket.com/escape-memory-leaks-javascript/

Bottom line, all array functions will clear up their memory stack after running.

Comment: Thank you; it definitely helps! However, I am not so worried about memory leaks. Do you think creating and destroying all those instances can generate worse performance than its counterpart, storing with an array reference and recycling this instance?

Comment: A reference is just a pointer. Use the same "storage" array or create a new one and point to that new one has the same final cost: 1 pointer. So unless you are on a language like C where you statically allocate memory (maybe a lot of it for every temp array creation), there is no relevance to "keeping" an array and operating inside of it.

Comment: This is not about declaration, this is about initialization, I mean, creating new instances of the array, like reduce, map, etc. do